# Lift checkbox "missing parameter type" error

Tags: lift

I can't understand why this code:

```
  var checked = Seq()

  SHtml.checkbox(Seq("1","2","3"), null, (checkedList) => checked = checkedList)
```

give me this error:

```
 missing parameter type
[error]   SHtml.checkbox(Seq("1","2","3"), null, (checkedList) => checked = checkedList)
[error]                                           ^
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I see here. First, since you are dealing with a typed `Seq`, your declaration of `checked` is likely to cause problems since it is currently  `Seq[Nothing]`. Try changing that to:

```
var checked = Seq.empty[String]
```

or

```
var checked:Seq[String] = Nil
```

either will give you the correct type for the options you have in the checkbox.

Then, for the actual SHtml.checkbox - the compiler is having trouble inferring the type. I'm not entirely sure why in this case, but since the signature is `SHtml.checkbox[T](Seq[T], Seq[T], (Seq[T]) => None)`. If the type can't be inferred, you can either:

Specify a type for `T` like:

```
 SHtml.checkbox[String](Seq("1","2","3"), null, (checkedList) => checked = checkedList)
```

or, explicitly type the input to your function like:

```
 SHtml.checkbox(Seq("1","2","3"), null, (checkedList:Seq[String]) => checked = checkedList)
```